# Why haven't I recieved my reputation for upvote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

[image]

Two upvotes and an accepted answer is not giving me rep. Why?

Comment: I think it has to do with the bounty that costs rep. Netto rep gain is still negative, so it doesn't show up here, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made your [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/63934/28778) community wiki. Reputation gained by accepted answers and votes (downvotes & upvotes) are not awarded for Community Wiki (CW) posts. Only a moderator will be able to revert the CW.

[image]

> ### How do Community Wiki posts work?
>
> Community wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community.  They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not contribute to any user's reputation.
>
> Some of the key features are:
>
> - A much lower reputation (**100** instead of **2000**) is needed to freely edit a community wiki post. <sup>1</sup>
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
> - Accepting an answer marked as community wiki [does not affect its original author's reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/152859), and [does not give +2 to the question author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297464/152859).
> - Bounties awarded to answer marked as community wiki give reputation as usual.
> - The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
> - The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.
> - The original author still receives notifications for edits or comments on the post.
> - The user listed in the author box need not be the original author. Rather, it is the user with the [highest percentage of authorship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guo7Nm.jpg) in the final revision, determined by the number of lines inserted or deleted, with a bonus (factor of 2) for the original author.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for more information.